# How to get back discarded commits

Tags: github

while working on a group project on a sourcetree, I discarded my group mates commits accidentally. Is there a way i can get it back? pls help!
I was trying to solve merge conflicts and didn't know I am discarding their commits

Answer (score 0):

One SourceTree-based way would be to:

- clone again the repo (in a new local path)
- add your old local repo as a remote and fetch from it
- recreate your branch (the one you were working on in the old repo) in the new repo
- redo your merge in the new repo.

Pure git-way would be to abort the current merge:

```
git merge --abort
```